# Hindi text to english transliteration for C#

Tags: c#, .net, transliteration, hindi

I am searching for a c# code that can be used to get Hindi text to English transliteration.

Also tell me if there is any api available for c#.

Comment: FYI, there's no such thing as "C#.NET". The language is named "C#".

Comment: There is a java api for translating text using the google translator. Its one easy way, you can create one like that for your c# lang too. You cant achieve without the google/some translators help. May be Skeet may know it :)

Comment: Note for future posters: He asks for transliteration, not translation. There's quite a big difference between those two!

Answer (score 2):

From what I see, this isn't an easy thing to do but it can be done.  Google has provided an API to help out:
http://www.techdreams.org/google/trick-to-use-google-indic-transliteration-service-in-c-java-php-and-other-programming-languages/1134-20090122

I know this is a broad answer but it matches the broadness of the question.  You will need to do the research on how to implement this in your code.

Answer (score 2):

There is a .NET library for transliteration on codeplex: http://unidecode.codeplex.com/ - it'd help.

Comment: Special symbols had to be replaced with its english analogue, like "éåäöíØ" => "eaaoiO"

Comment: @Evgeny: more like Cyrillic to Latin alphabets

Comment: @Evgeny: Fyi, the special symbols being replaced with an latin-alphabet analogue, is not a suitable solution for transliteration. The same thing happens with Greek when an unsuitable encoding is used, and believe me, the result bears no resemblance to the real transliteration.

Comment: @John: as I understand it can be done for every unicode letter, including Chinese, Cyrillic, Umlauts and etc.

Comment: @Evgeny: could you please post a comment with your name written in Cyrillic? If I recall correctly, it's almost the same characters either way, but I decided not to insult your name by guessing.

Comment: @John: "Евгений" - My name is, unfortunately, very badly transliterated - to many options.

Comment: @Evgeny: "Евгений" to "Evgeny" is transliteration. "Евгений" to "Eugene" is translation.

Comment: Yes, folks, I realized what is my mistake. Not in all cases, possible to choose an adequate equivalent.

Comment: @Evgeny: yeah, that "ий"  doesn't make it easy. "y" or "iy" or "i" or ...

Comment: Transliteration from a language to another is usually really hard, especially if the target language does not contain phonemes that are used in the source one. I just heard your name from the listen function of google translate, and it's a lot harder to transliterate it in English than we thought! Yuvguiñi in Spanish or Γιουβγκίνι in Greek might be more accurate, heh!

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7+ can do this for Hindi/Devanagari with [Extended Linguistic Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2009/10/26/7-on-7-extended-linguistic-services.aspx). (You'll need the [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) to do it from .NET.)